# I can't run database analyse in CodeQL

Tags: code-analysis, codeql

I can't successfully launch a database analyse command.

I tried to launch it like this:

```
codeql database analyze test $HOME/codeql-home/codeql-repo/cpp/ql/examples/snippets/function_call.ql --format=csv --output=c_test.csv
```

I got this error:

> is not compatible with the QL library
> ../codeql-home/codeql-repo/cpp/ql/examples/snippets/function_call.ql
> uses. The database may be too new for the QL libraries the query is
> using; try upgrading them.

With any code repository, I got this error and with any .ql file.

I checked CodeQL resolve languages and CodeQL resolve qlpacks and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the steps in the [documentation](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-cli/getting-started-with-the-codeql-cli/)?
In particular, are you using the (latest) `lgtm.com` branch of `github/codeql`?
This branch should always be compatible with the (latest) CLI release.